# How can a currency be added to Ripple?

Tags: ripple

I would like to add New Israeli Shekels (ILS) into Ripple.

How do I go about doing that?

To clarify, when I try to enter ILS in the Trust page, it doesn't recognize it.

[image]

I see that I can still add it, and in fact add arbitrary currencies such as XYZ (Ripple shorterns whatever I enter in the currency box to three letters if it doesn't recognize it).

1. Why doesn't ILS appear in the autocomplete box?
2. What does it mean that I trust someone with 1 XYZ or ZYX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In next deploy client will save used currencies and suggest them :)

https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple-client/commit/77a11af31bf44875f19935ed9ea6fa8e2c412602

and

https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple-client/commit/1a44e94844d6948d103e31c6121dcb71d5b65ef1

update: the change is already live.

Comment: Hi! Could you add a link to a source?

Comment: sure. see edit.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the reason why it is not added is because it wasn't considered "one of the main ones" whatever that means. You can write ILS yourself though: you can use whatever three letter code you like.

Alice trusts Bob for 10 XYZ.

Alice and Bob know what XYZ represent. If you and your friends (ripple neighbors) use ILS, you know it represents New Israeli Shekels, the system only needs to know that it is the same currency so that it can apply a 1:1 exchange rate.
For more information on this, read this issue and this forum post:

https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple-client/issues/77

https://ripple.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=7

EDIT: To trade ILS, manually edit the text within the selector for the currency pair. For example, substitute "XRP/BTC" for "BTC/ILS" and that's it. Of course you need to specify the issuer for ILS and BTC as always.

EDIT2: Now currencies will be ordered upon usage. The more you use a currency, the higher it will appear on the selector's list.
https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple-client/commit/1a44e94844d6948d103e31c6121dcb71d5b65ef1

Comment: So this question is how to add ILS to "the main ones".

Comment: For that you need to modify the client. Currently the client only lets certain pairs of currencies to be traded, but having two selectors (one for each currency) on the trading page instead of just one would allow you to trade ILS for BTC or XRP, for example.
THERE'S NO DIFFERENCE ON HOW ILS and USD are treated aside from this one. The system itself doesn't really "care much" about currencies.

Comment: So, should I open a github issue?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I've been talking with arthur and you can directly edit the text in the currency-pair selector. I'll adapt my answer for this.

Comment: What I'm asking is how to make ILS appear as "one of the main currencies" for all users of the Ripple client, not just how to trade it myself. Who should I talk to?

Comment: For that the client must be modified, so yes, open an issue on the client's github.

Comment: https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple-client/issues/265

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add ILS - It supports all ISO4217 currencies. [This is the line that adds ILS](https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple-client/blob/master/src/js/data/iso4217.js#L82).